# Matplotlib - How can I add labels to legend

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend

Here I am trying to separate the data with the factor male or not by plotting Age on x-axis and Fare on y-axis and I want to display two labels in the legend differentiating male and female with respective colors.Can anyone help me do this.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://sololearn.com/uploads/files/titanic.csv')
df['male']=df['Sex']=='male'
sc1= plt.scatter(df['Age'],df['Fare'],c=df['male'])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `seaborn` library which builds on top of `matplotlib` to perform the exact task you require. You can scatterplot `'Age'` vs `'Fare'` and colour code it by `'Sex'` by just passing the `hue` parameter in `sns.scatterplot`, as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure()

# No need to call plt.legend, seaborn will generate the labels and legend
# automatically.
sns.scatterplot(df['Age'], df['Fare'], hue=df['Sex'])

plt.show()
```

Seaborn generates nicer plots with less code and more functionality.

You can install `seaborn` from PyPI using `pip install seaborn`.

Refer: [Seaborn docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html)

Answer (score 1):

[`PathCollection.legend_elements`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection.legend_elements) method
can be used to steer how many legend entries are to be created and how they
should be labeled.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://sololearn.com/uploads/files/titanic.csv')
df['male'] = df['Sex']=='male'

sc1= plt.scatter(df['Age'], df['Fare'], c=df['male'])

plt.legend(handles=sc1.legend_elements()[0], labels=['male', 'female'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

[Legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html) and [Scatter plots with a legend](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html#automated-legend-creation) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by segregating the data in two separate dataframe and then, label can be set for these dataframe.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://sololearn.com/uploads/files/titanic.csv')
subset1 = df[(df['Sex'] == 'male')]
subset2 = df[(df['Sex'] != 'male')]
plt.scatter(subset1['Age'], subset1['Fare'], label = 'Male')
plt.scatter(subset2['Age'], subset2['Fare'], label = 'Female')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRxZ3.png)